# escaping a text string before json

Tags: javascript, php, json, xml, string

Im converting a XML document to JSON from PHP backend and returning it to frontend using ajax like so:

print_r(json_encode($result_xml));

The response can be seen here: https://api.myjson.com/bins/6ndc7

the problem is that $result_xml also contains some text right before that response which is the following:

URL: http://sandbox.cargonizer.no/transport_agreements.xml<'br>
Took 2.178947 seconds to send a request to http://sandbox.cargonizer.no/transport_agreements.xml<'br>

(without the single-quote in <'br>)

So my question is: How can I ignore the first two lines of string?

Answer (score 0):

Split the $result_xml variable and then send only xml for parsing.

Comment: Ok ill try that. Thank you for your response. Greatly appreciated :)